# Performing network scan requiring permission for coarse location

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-permissions

I am working on an app which does a network scan and puts all the found SSIDs into a spinner.

Android Studio warns that you need permission for `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`. Upon adding this into the manifest, Android Studio doesn't give any warning by the `WifiManager.getScanResults()` returns 0 networks. I've found that I need to add/request permission for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`.

All I need is the network SSID, I don't care where the user is located, so why do I/the user need to allow the location permission just to get a list of available networks. Below is how I am currently doing the scan:

```
    activity.registerReceiver(mWifiScannerReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
            wifiManager = (WifiManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

            wifiManager.startScan();

And my receiver:

if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION))
            {
                List<ScanResult> scanResults = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                wifiNetworkList.clear();
                //List<String> ssids = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < scanResults.size(); i++)
                {
                    wifiNetworkList.add(scanResults.get(i).SSID);
                    //ssids.add(scanResults.get(i).SSID);
                }
                //wifiNetworkList = ssids;
                wifiAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't care where the user is located

Yes, but given the network SSID, you can find out where the user is located, if the location of that WiFi network is known.

> why do I/the user need to allow the location permission just to get a list of available networks

For improved user privacy, [as of Android 6.0](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id).

Comment: I understand the user has to request permission as part of Android 6. That's not the issue I have. From a user perspective, I think its quite confusing for a user, who has an app that is allowing them to select a specific network SSID, the app has nothing to do with location, but the user is having to give permission to access their location. I would imagine a lot of users who don't understand would just deny location, then wonder why no networks are being listed

Comment: @Boardy: "I understand the user has to request permission as part of Android 6" -- my link is not to the runtime permission documentation. It is to the "Access to Hardware Identifier" documentation in the Android 6.0 release notes that mentions the specific behavior that you dislike. Your job is to explain to users why you need this permission and the ramifications of them denying that permission. Neither the user nor Android can confirm that you are not somehow using the SSIDs to identify the user's location.

Comment: @Boardy: hardware macaddress(BSSID) of wireless networks(wifi routers) are unique. imagine I have database of all bssids in a particular area, and i know exact location of each wireless routers. You entered that area with your app doing a wifi scan. means your app will get the your (user) location. For that your app needs user's permission to give scanresults(indirectly your location).